# How to import go modules into /*_test.go files?

Tags: go

How do I import my functions into my testing folder? I ran `go mod init` in the cmd directory and it created a go.mod file with `module "cmd"`, however when I try to import it in testing, I'm unable to access to functions. I am running `go test ./test` in root project directory and error is: `test/services_test.go:4:2: "cmd" is not an importable package;`

```
myproject
├── cmd
     ├── main.go (package main)
     ├── helper.go (package main)
     └── services.go (package main)
├── test
     ├── helper_test.go (package_main)
     └── services_test.go (package main)
├── go.mod (module cmd)
└── go.sum
```

In cmd/services.go

```golang
package main

func doStuff() { 
  // TODO
}
```

In test/services_test.go

```golang
package main

import {
    "cmd"
    "testing"
}

func TestdoStuff (*testing.T) {
    cmd.doStuff()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The tests for a given package should be *in that package* so that they can see unexported variables, fields, and methods of that package, and don't need to import that package at all. Don't put them in a separate `test` directory.

You can import *other* packages if necessary to test this one, but you won't be able to see unexported stuff from other packages. Tests are no different from any other file in that regard.

Comment: Tests should ideally exercise the same API that users of the package will use — otherwise the test might miss bugs (or awkward aspects of the API) that real users will encounter, or it may even be impossible for users to write their own tests using the package API.

Comment: The more important reason to put tests in the same directory as the package under test is so that downstream users will be able to find the test. If a user of the package runs `go test all`, they will run the tests colocated with the packages they import, but will not run tests in other locations.

Comment: it is a common approach also to test packages from outside to create less coupled and more independent tests: 
1. https://github.com/quii/learn-go-with-tests/blob/main/reading-files/blogposts_test.go ,
2. https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/structuring-tests-in-go-46ddee7a25c

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in others answers, test files have to be in the **same** directory as the tested file.
You can check out the tutorial [Create a Go Module](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/create-module) and then [Add a Test](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/add-a-test).

Here are the examples from these tutorials:

```
myproject
├── greetings
     ├── greetings.go (package greetings)
     ├── greetings_test.go (package greetings)
├── go.mod
└── go.sum
```

The greetings.go file:

```golang
package greetings

import "fmt"

// Hello returns a greeting for the named person.
func Hello(name string) string {
    // Return a greeting that embeds the name in a message.
    message := fmt.Sprintf("Hi, %v. Welcome!", name)
    return message
}
```

And greetings_test.go file with two tests:

```golang
package greetings

import (
    "testing"
    "regexp"
)

// TestHelloName calls greetings.Hello with a name, checking
// for a valid return value.
func TestHelloName(t *testing.T) {
    name := "Gladys"
    want := regexp.MustCompile(`\b`+name+`\b`)
    msg, err := Hello("Gladys")
    if !want.MatchString(msg) || err != nil {
        t.Fatalf(`Hello("Gladys") = %q, %v, want match for %#q, nil`, msg, err, want)
    }
}

// TestHelloEmpty calls greetings.Hello with an empty string,
// checking for an error.
func TestHelloEmpty(t *testing.T) {
    msg, err := Hello("")
    if msg != "" || err == nil {
        t.Fatalf(`Hello("") = %q, %v, want "", error`, msg, err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiled artifact for a `package main` is a binary, and that binary is what downstream users of the package will interact with. So a test that verifies the behavior of `package main` should *test against the binary itself,* not the individual functions used to implement that binary.

You can write such a test by using the `os/exec` package to run `go build cmd` (perhaps using the `-o` flag to output the binary to the test's temporary directory), then using the `os/exec` package to execute the resulting binary.

Or, use a third-party testing package such as [`github.com/rogpeppe/testscript`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rogpeppe/testscript) to write more concise script-driven tests.

Or, factor out any helper-functions into [`internal` packages](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Internal_Directories) and test the [exported functions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) of those packages.

---

With any of those approaches, the tests for a given package still belong in the same directory as that package. That way, when users run `go test cmd` they can be confident that `cmd` actually works — if the test is in a different package, they won't obviously know to run `go test test` in order to test the `cmd` package.